# How to print vertical progress bar in console using Java?

Tags: java, command-line, console, terminal, progress-bar

How can we print a vertical progress bar in terminal console or command prompt using Java? A horizontal bar looks like this:

```
user#java PrintHorizontalProgressBar
5%#####
```

I want to print same progress bar but vertically.

Comment: Why my rating is being voted down? I made thorough research before asking this! In fact, I've been trying this since last 3 days!

Comment: If you had researched this for the last few days, you might have some attempt to show? If you can show that, please flag this question for moderator attention to be reviewed. If you are completely stuck at where to begin, perhaps explain what in your research did not make sense? Questions asking "please do this for me" (such as this appears to be) solicit many negative reactions from our community. I'm closing this now.

Comment: @Tim: I don't feel my question as "please do this for me". I provided all possible information. But, within few moments, my question was closed. Very sad!

Answer (score 2):

Did you try to use `System.out.println("*")`? It is a sort of vertical progress bar.

Comment: Of course. But, I want to make the % figure constant at the beginning. Just like for a horizontal progress bar: 5%##### 6%###### etc.

Comment: http://nakkaya.com/2009/11/08/command-line-progress-bar/ shows a horizontal progress bar. I am trying to print same bar vertically.

Comment: you can do it but it will be terminal specific. At least code that will work on linux will not work on windows and vice versa. You have to search for terminal escape characters. I once implemented something similar for linux only. I do not have the code right now but I remember that I performed reverse engineering of ant logger that printed failures using red color. So I understood how does it work and implemented my own code. I believe that some googling will bring you a java library that supports terminal escape sequences. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks so much! Yeah, I googled and found few different ways. I really don't understand why my question was voted down and closed?! That too within few minutes of asking! So quick?! I felt very much sad. I provided all the possible links and information and honestly asked.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = 0; i < maxProgress; i++) System.out.println("#");
```

[EDIT] Honestly, it was half a joke. I am not sure to see the usefulness of such progress bar...
Now, to make my answer more useful, I think you might want to take a look at the [Jansi](http://jansi.fusesource.org/) project, it allows cross-platform handling of Ansi codes, including on the non-Dos Windows consoles that doesn't handle them easily.

Comment: Thanks! Did you see the progress % in the beginning? For a vertical bar, how to show the percentage at the same place?

Comment: Thanks! I didn't think of usefulness when I asked this question. I wrote 3 lines of code that nicely prints horizontal progress bar showing the %age as well. I thought, perhaps I could try for vertical progress bar now. I tried and was unsuccessful. So, I asked the community. I really don't understand what's wrong in my question. Why so quick it was closed?!? And why voted down?

Comment: @Faisal: honestly, I don't know why it is voted down/closed, but I feel you should have given more information: you show what a horizontal bar looks like (with lack of formatting, so hard to understand), but not what a vertical one should look like. You have no precise goal beside curiosity (which is OK), so no precise specification. And see Tim's explanations too.